# Is it possible to create with webpack multiple css bundle files?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I need to create three bundle style files.

Is it possible to exclude two specific files (file1.scss, file2.scss) and to output them to two separate files - in such a way that in the end I have 3 different bundle files: 
**allFilesExcept1and2.css**, 
**file1.css**, 
**file2.css**

In webpack I am loading the scss files like this:

```
test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    fallback: 'style-loader',
    use: [ {
        loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
    }, {
        loader: "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
     }]
})
```

The intend is to always include allFilesExcept1and2.css in the `index.html` but conditionally include `file1.css` or `file2.css`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the exclude and/or include [options](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#condition) available in the loader parameter object.